# I want to know is there any function or method to check first either file is created or not

Tags: c++

I want to know is there any function or method to check first either file is created or not if it created read the information otherwise skip the file reading process.

Comment: i use good() function and its work fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool file_does_exist(const std::string &filename) {
    return std::ifstream(filename);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply open the file for reading

```
std::fstream fs;
fs.open ("test.txt", std::fstream::in);
```

and then check if everything is allright

```
if(fs.good())
   //...
```

Answer (score 0):

The question's not too clear, but do you mean this?

```
std::ifstream file("file_name.ext");
if (file)
{
  read_from(file);
}
```